postsrsd forwarding problems with mail from domain using DMARC
I am using postsrsd to tackle the problems with forwarding email and SPF / DKIM / DMARC issues on my mailserver. However, if i receive mails from domains using DMARC, the forwarded mails are bouncing from a few ESP (f.e. Outlook). Emails to Gmail are delivered as expected and when checking the source it says the SPF is PASS (my mailservers IP) but DKIM (original sender) and DMARC are on FAIL.
The route the mails are going is (info@sender.com to info@receiver.com): info@sender.com to spamserver running MailScanner (spamfilter.mydomain.com) and then to mailserver (mail.mydomain.com). Here it is locally stored in info@receiver.com's mailbox or if forwarded sent to forwarded@outlook.com using postsrd.
My main.cf for postsrsd is:
sender_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10001
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:10002
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient
postsrsd version is 1.4
Error from outlook in mail.log is:
dsn=5.7.509, status=bounced (host hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[52.101.11.20] said: 550 5.7.509 Access denied, sending domain [LINKEDIN.COM] does not pass DMARC verification and has a DMARC policy of reject.
Does Anyone have a working forwarding with postfix and postsrsd? Using another methos is no problem since I am trying to solve this for over 2 days now.

Does this happen with all emails forwarded to e.g. outlook.com email addresses? Or is this specific to a combination of sender domain (LinkedIn.com) and Receiving ESP (Outlook.com)?
https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd has a FAQ in the readme addressing this issue.

It happens, when a sender email has DKIM/DMarc enabled and to more ESP's. As Gmail says the SPF record is OK (my mail server) but DKIM and therefore DMARC aren't it seems that the mails are rewritten wrongly or something.

please add code blocks

I suspect the email envelope from address is rewritten correctly, but no longer aligns with the Header FROM domain. So, you would need a successful DKIM result, aligned with the Header FROM domain for DMARC to pass.

Yes, I think you're right. That's why Gmail says the spf is OK (my mailserver) and dkim and dmarc are wrong. However, opendkim won't sign the outgoing mail if it rewritten by postsrsd. I think if opendkim would sign the mail with the dkim from my mailserver it would work also.
